# How do I generate observations between two dates using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in the following format:

```
User ID   Start Date   End Date
1         '2000-01-01' '2000-03-01'
2         '2002-01-01' '2002-08-01'
...         ....         ....
10        '2003-03-01' '2004-01-01'
```

How do I generate a dataset with each date between the start date and the end date for each user as follows:

```
User ID   Start Date  End Date      Activity Date
1         '2000-01-01' '2000-03-01' '2000-01-01'
1         '2000-01-01' '2000-03-01' '2000-02-01' 
1         '2000-01-01' '2000-03-01' '2000-03-01' 
2         '2002-01-01' '2002-08-01'  '2002-01-01'
...         ....           ...           ...
2         '2002-01-01' '2002-08-01'  '2002-07-01'
2         '2002-01-01' '2002-08-01'  '2002-08-01'
...         ....           ...           ...
...         ....           ...           ...
10        '2003-03-01' '2004-01-01'  '2003-03-01'
10        '2003-03-01' '2004-01-01'  '2003-04-01'
...         ....           ...           ...
...         ....           ...           ...
10        '2003-03-01' '2004-01-01'  '2003-12-01'
10        '2003-03-01' '2004-01-01'  '2004-01-01'
```

Comment: You want the max date and min date for each user, right?

Answer (score 7):

Use `pd.date_range` to generate dates from your start date to your end date. I have set the frequency to 30 days by doing `freq=30D` - choose whatever convenient for you.

```
df['Activity Date'] = df.apply(lambda s: pd.date_range(s['Start Date'], s['End Date'], freq='30D').tolist(), 1)
df = df.explode('Activity Date')
```

---

```
   User ID Start Date   End Date Activity Date
0        1 2000-01-01 2000-03-01    2000-01-01
0        1 2000-01-01 2000-03-01    2000-01-31
0        1 2000-01-01 2000-03-01    2000-03-01
1        2 2002-01-01 2002-08-01    2002-01-01
1        2 2002-01-01 2002-08-01    2002-01-31
1        2 2002-01-01 2002-08-01    2002-03-02
1        2 2002-01-01 2002-08-01    2002-04-01
1        2 2002-01-01 2002-08-01    2002-05-01
1        2 2002-01-01 2002-08-01    2002-05-31
1        2 2002-01-01 2002-08-01    2002-06-30
1        2 2002-01-01 2002-08-01    2002-07-30
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-03-01
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-03-31
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-04-30
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-05-30
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-06-29
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-07-29
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-08-28
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-09-27
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-10-27
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-11-26
2       10 2003-03-01 2004-01-01    2003-12-26
```

Comment: I think `freq = 'MS'`

Comment: Any ideas why I am receiving this error : 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @J.K the `explode` method is available for pandas versions 0.25.0+. Check your version with `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: `.tolist()` is not necessary. List like is enough for `explode`

Comment: @rafaelc, I solved the answer using apply in the 10 min. then I spent more than an hour trying to explode the cell :). Thank you ! , I added my solution as an answer below.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. However, the method did not work out for me. I got an value error saying that the dimension of value passed is not the same as the index implied. I guess the reason is that the number of activity dates for each User ID is not identical. My pandas version is still 0.20.3. This might be part of the reason.

Answer (score 2):

#### Comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([
    t + (d,) for t in zip(*map(df.get, df))
    for d in pd.date_range(t[1], t[2], freq='MS')
], columns=[*df, 'Activity Date'])

    User ID  Start Date    End Date Activity Date
0         1  2000-01-01  2000-03-01    2000-01-01
1         1  2000-01-01  2000-03-01    2000-02-01
2         1  2000-01-01  2000-03-01    2000-03-01
3         2  2002-01-01  2002-08-01    2002-01-01
4         2  2002-01-01  2002-08-01    2002-02-01
5         2  2002-01-01  2002-08-01    2002-03-01
6         2  2002-01-01  2002-08-01    2002-04-01
7         2  2002-01-01  2002-08-01    2002-05-01
8         2  2002-01-01  2002-08-01    2002-06-01
9         2  2002-01-01  2002-08-01    2002-07-01
10        2  2002-01-01  2002-08-01    2002-08-01
11       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-03-01
12       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-04-01
13       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-05-01
14       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-06-01
15       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-07-01
16       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-08-01
17       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-09-01
18       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-10-01
19       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-11-01
20       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2003-12-01
21       10  2003-03-01  2004-01-01    2004-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use apply method, row by row, and then explode the acitivitydate column.

Create new dataframe and convert strings to datetime :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta 

d = {'User ID': [1], 'Start Date': ['2000-01-01'],'End Date':['2000-01-10']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df1['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Start Date'])
df1['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['End Date'])
df1
```

df1 :

```
    User ID Start Date  End Date
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-05
1   2   2000-02-01  2000-02-20
```

For each row, pass the start and the end date to the function "check" :

```
df1['ActivityDate'] = df1.apply(lambda row: check(row['Start Date'],row['End Date']),axis=1)
df1 = df1.explode('ActivityDate')  
df1
```

Result :

```
    User ID Start Date  End Date    ActivityDate
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-01
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-02
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-03
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-04
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-05
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-06
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-07
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-08
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-09
0   1   2000-01-01  2000-01-10  2000-01-10
```

A Simple function below to get all dates between the start and the end date, and return the result as an array. This function will be called once for each row.

```
def check(start,end):  
    Result = []
    while start <= end:
        Result.append(start)
        start = start + timedelta(days=1)
    return Result
```